# Alter header content type in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm using an external form to add an item to Shopify's cart from a remote page (a mobile app). When this form gets submitted, Shopify redirects you to a page you can set. I created a page called item added that simply returns to all the items currently in the cart in JSON. The idea is that my mobile app will read this JSON response and handle it.

I don't know how to set the header content type in oder for my library on the app side to handle the response (I am using RESTKIT). In php its really easy.

`header('Content-Type: application/json');`

My question is if I can do this in Liquid Markup. And if not, are their any other solutions to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shopify is a fully hosted SAAS service. There's some deep server side pieces you're not allowed to modify/alter. Those are (as of today): robots.txt, sitemap.xml, http headers among others.